# Escaping regex sed (1 lowercase, 1 uppercase, 1 symbol, 1 number) for bash

Tags: sed, regular-expression

The goal is to remove every line not containing one uppercase, one lowercase, one special character and one number from a file.

I am unable to run this regex:

```
(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$
```

As in the bash command:

```
sed -ri '\/(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$\/!d' rh.txt
```

As the error is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 67: unterminated address regex
```

I am unsure what to escape.

Any help here?

Comment: Do not escape slash `/`

Comment: Then I'd get: `sed: -e expression #1, char 63: Invalid preceding regular expression`

Comment: I dont think sed does non-greedy `.*?` nor `(?=` lookahead perl stuff.

Comment: Yes, because you are using lookahead, which is PCRE feature, not the one your sed use.

Comment: Can you please suggest another command to perform the required?

Comment: Is it atleast 1 of each or exactly one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `sed` for this; use an inverse `grep`.  That way you can use the PCRE-style expressions you're trying to shoehorn into `sed` (which doesn't speak PCRE):

```
grep -v -P '^(?=.*pattern1)(?=.*pattern2)'
```

Comment: `grep -v -P '^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$' < rh.txt` is not doing what is required, though it works on online regexrs.

Comment: Start with breaking it into smaller pieces to make sure they're doing what you think they are.  Also, try _not_ using `-v`; make it print _only_ the lines you want to exclude, then add `-v` to reverse the search results.

Comment: Ahh actually I needed it without the `-v`. Works perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error you got due to escaping slash `/`, which make `/` is not delimiter for address pattern anymore.

Now, even you don't escape `/`, then your regex won't work. `sed` only support `BRE`, and `ERE` in some implementation (and will become standard in next POSIX version). `BRE` or `ERE` don't support lookahead feature, which you used in your regex `(?=...)`.

To archive your requirement:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -e '
  /[A-Z]/!d
  /[a-z]/!d
  /[0-9]/!d
  /[#?!@$%^&*-]/!d
' <file
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/[A-Z]/{/[a-z]/{/[0-9]/{/[#?!@$%^&*-]/p}}}'
```